Unable to adda remote Swift package to my project in Xcode
I wish to add the Swift Factory package as a remote package to my project. Selecting File -> Add Package Dependencies in Xcode 16.2 displays the package selection screen. This screen cannot resolve the Recently Used packages and similarly fails to complete after entering the URL in the search field (see attached image).

I confirmed the URL resolves to an actual page. I have tried Reset Package Caches, restarting Xcode, and restarting the machine without any improvement. I have also confirmed that the project is not using the Legacy build location.
The Bitbucket Cloud account is used for source control. The Github account is not currently associated with any repositories. Therefore I removed the Github account - so only one source control account is active - and this allowed me to refresh the Bitbucket account to see its linked repositories. However, I still could not resolve the Github package search. I added the Factory repository to my Favorites in Github. This also had no effect.
